# Como fazer um preview do título do arquivo selecionado via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, upload

Tenho um código para pré visualização de upload de imagens em Javascript.
Porém gostaria de usar com formato documento, para que ao invés de mostrar a imagem que será carregada, mostrar apenas o nome do arquivo pdf/word ou um ícone também.

Código que já tenho feito:

```js
function handleFileSelect() {
    //Check File API support
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {

        var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
        var output = document.getElementById("result");

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            //Only pics
            if (!file.type.match('image')) continue;

            var picReader = new FileReader();
            picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
                var picFile = event.target;
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" + "title='" + picFile.name + "'/>";
                output.insertBefore(div, null);
            });
            //Read the image
            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<label for="files">Select multiple files:</label>
    <input id="files" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    <output id="result" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já que não vai usar imagens para ver um *preview* delas, você pode dispensar a API `FileReader()` e usar o código abaixo para pegar o nome do arquivo e exibir um ícone (se for word ou pdf):

```js
function handleFileSelect() {
 var output = document.getElementById("result");
 arquivos = $("#files").prop("files");
 var nomes = $.map(arquivos, function(val) { return val.name; });
 for(x=0;x<nomes.length;x++){
  var extensao = nomes[x].split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
  var nome = nomes[x].substring(nomes[x].lastIndexOf("/"),nomes[x].length);
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  if(extensao == "doc" || extensao == "docx"){
   icone = "http://jonvilma.com/images/word-14.jpg";
  }else if(extensao == "pdf"){
   icone = "http://iconbug.com/data/5b/507/52ff0e80b07d28b590bbc4b30befde52.png";
  }else{
   icone = "https://orig01.deviantart.net/244d/f/2013/087/8/0/no_icon_by_slamiticon-d5z70lm.png";
  }
  div.innerHTML = "<img src='"+icone+"' height='24' /> "+nome;
  output.insertBefore(div, null);
 }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="files">Select multiple files:</label>
    <input id="files" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    <output id="result" />
```